# Why does my function to check whether a letter is in a string loop infinitely?

Tags: python

```
def is_in(char, Astr):
    while len(Astr) > 1:
        if char == Astr[(int(len(Astr)/2)) :  -(int(len(Astr)/2))]:
            return True
        elif char > Astr[(int(len(Astr)/2)) :  -(int(len(Astr)/2))]: 
            is_in(char, Astr[int(len(Astr)/2):])
        elif char < Astr[(int(len(Astr)/2)) :  -(int(len(Astr)/2))]:
            is_in(char, Astr[:int(len(Astr)/2)])
    else:
        return False
```

It's supposed to take in a character and a string, and spit out a boolean. But it's looping infinitely **even when given a character that is in string.**

Comment: Are you trying to binary search a string? I'm not sure it makes sense. Anyway, you don't return anything from the recursive calls

Comment: You never seem to change `Astr`, so `len(Astr) > 1` will always be `True` if it's `True` one time

Comment: Bisection search, it's an exercise, but there's no feedback and I don't know why it's not working :(.

Comment: I doubt that you need a while loop *and* recursion. You should probably use one or the other.

Comment: re: _"there's no feedback and I don't know why it's not working"_:  you might find these useful [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
 and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: khelwood, I removed the while loop, and somehow it's still  looping

Comment: Pranav, I spent a solid hour trying to figure it out myself, using the rubber duck method, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Is this meant to be some kind of binary search? If so, *Astr* need to be sorted (which it may be). Unless the string is **very** long (and sorted) there's no benefit to this over the built-in *in* operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def is_in(char, Astr):

    if char == Astr[(int(len(Astr)/2))]:
        return True
    elif len(Astr) < 2: 
        return False
    elif char > Astr[(int(len(Astr)/2))]: 
        return (is_in(char, Astr[(int(len(Astr)/2) +1):]))
    elif char < Astr[(int(len(Astr)/2))]:
        return (is_in(char, Astr[:int(len(Astr)/2)]))
```

This worked.

I made 4 changes:

1. Removed While loop
2. Removed second part of string slicing (realized it was not necessary at all)
3. Added the False statement as the first ELIF statement.
4. Added a "+1" to the slice of our third return, since due to how slicing works it was inclusive of the already evaluated middle character in the IF statement.

Not sure which one did it, but there you go I suppose since this isn't getting an answer.